# Hudson - Maven 3 - unable to build

Tags: hudson, maven-3

I am having problems building a maven 3 pom:

```
[seam] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java -cp /home/walterjwhite/.hudson/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-agent-1.372.jar:/opt/apache/maven/3.0.beta.1/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.2.3.jar hudson.maven.agent.Main /opt/apache/maven/3.0.beta.1 /opt/apache/tomcat/6.0.29/webapps/hudson/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-1.372.jar /home/walterjwhite/.hudson/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-interceptor-1.372.jar 37568 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.getWorld()Lorg/codehaus/classworlds/ClassWorld;
 at hudson.maven.agent.Main.main(Main.java:115)
 at hudson.maven.agent.Main.main(Main.java:62)
ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1 Finished: FAILURE
```

I can build this just fine locally, but Hudson is doing its own thing.  I read that Hudson will support Maven 3, but what can I do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like [HUDSON-4988](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-4988) which is not fixed. Use Maven 2 with Hudson for now.

Comment: Unfortunately, a JBoss artifact I'm trying to use apparently has a requirement on Maven 3.

Comment: @Walter Do you have a link to its pom?

Comment: @Pascal - http://github.com/walterjwhite/project.configuration/blob/master/poms/dependencyManagement/seam/base.xml

Comment: @Walter I meant a link to *THE* artifact that is causing problems.

Comment: I figured as much, the artifact that I need is org.jboss.seam.seam-persistence:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.  I think it is the JBoss Spec Java EE 6 that is the problem.

Comment: @Walter I figured out that it was this artifact... I'm just asking for a link to its pom :)

Comment: It has now been fixed. The latest version supports Maven 3.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you can't execute it as a maven build in hudson, you could still execute Maven 3 as a shell task in a freestyle build. This is not a best practice, but a workaround if you can't build otherwise.

Comment: Ok, I will probably not do this since it isn't recommended.  I will just execute my builds from the command-line, it doesn't happen automatically, but for the time-being, it works.  Any estimates as to when maven 3 (beta) will be supported?

Comment: If you're using command-line then it amounts to the same thing.  When @seanizer says it's not a "best practice", it's because it's much nicer when you can use Hudson's built-in Maven cleverness.  But since you can't do that, you might as well use a freestyle build.

Answer (score 3):

There is a known bug with Maven 3 and Hudson.  Olivier Lamy put out a wonderful fix for us as a Christmas present:

[Hudson War 1.389](http://people.apache.org/~olamy/hudson/main-maven3-support/hudson.war)

This will allow you to use Maven 3 with Hudson.  I have 0 errors at this point and it was easy to set up.

Comment: Exactly v1.389 triggers the above mentioned problem for me. The seems to be fixed in v1.398 (worked for me).